# Scraping fanduel through network requests and selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

I'm trying to scrape data from different markets on fanduel, I can see a lot of the data I want in a json from the network requests but the data only couples "market ids" with the odds. These market ids are random numbers so I don't really have any way to couple all the odds with what the odds are actually for. I was thinking about using selenium to just manually read off all the markets and odds instead because I can't really find a way to do it with requests. This is more of a strategic question, I'm not very experienced so I don't know if I'm being stupid or not. This could be an example page, but any page with odds would work.

https://sportsbook.fanduel.com/ice-hockey/nhl---matches/dallas-stars-@-vegas-golden-knights-32366023?tab=goal-scorer